# Pandas count returning count of each column and not singular value from within logic statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

I have a df that looks like this:

```
id   message    cate           score
1    abc        positive        1
2    def        negative        2
3    ghi        neutral         3
```

I want to get a count of every time `positive` appears:

I tried this:

```
df_sentences[df_sentences.cate =='positive'].count()
```

it returns:

```
id         1
message    1
cate       1
score      1
```

When I try below line I get `nan` in the new column:

```
df_sentences['total_count_positive'] = df_sentences[df_sentences.cate =='positive'].count()
```

How would I make new df to look like this?:

```
id   message    cate           score   total_count_positive total_count_negative    total_count_neutral

    1    abc        positive        1              1           1           
                                                                     1
    2    def        negative        2
    3    ghi        neutral         3
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you want the empty rows

Comment: the only other column that will be added is total_count_neutral

Comment: tried my best to add it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count works for me.

```
In [294]: df['total_positive'] = df.cate[df.cate == 'positive'].count()

In [296]: df['total_negative'] = df.cate[df.cate == 'negative'].count()

In [297]: df['total_neutral'] = df.cate[df.cate == 'neutral'].count()

In [298]: df['total_x'] = df.cate[df.cate == 'x'].count()       # to show it's actually counting something

In [299]: df
Out[299]:
   id message      cate  score  total_positive  total_negative  total_neutral  total_x
0   1     abc  positive      1               1               1              1        0
1   2     def  negative      2               1               1              1        0
2   3     ghi   neutral      3               1               1              1        0
```

A better way of doing it which will work without a prior knowledge of all of the unique values of `cate` is to use `value_counts()`. This method returns the summary data in a `Series` which we can use to add to the `DataFrame`.

```
In [307]: for i, c in enumerate(df.cate.value_counts()):
     ...:     tag = df.cate.value_counts().index[i]
     ...:     df[tag + '_count'] = c
     ...:

In [308]: df
Out[308]:
   id message      cate  score  neutral_count  negative_count  positive_count
0   1     abc  positive      1              1               1               1
1   2     def  negative      2              1               1               1
2   3     ghi   neutral      3              1               1               1
```

Finally, I wouldn't store the summary in the `DataFrame` at all because we can just use `value_counts()` and can access individual values like a `dict`.

```
In [313]: df.cate.value_counts()
Out[313]:
neutral     1
negative    1
positive    1
Name: cate, dtype: int64

In [312]: df.cate.value_counts()['positive']
Out[312]: 1
```

If you're working with a particularly large `DataFrame` and it's expensive to keep performing `value_counts()`, you can just assign it to some variable for later use as well.